# How to make specified nav-bar contents to dissapear after a successful user login?

Tags: php, session, html-lists, require

So in my `index.php` I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php include 'includes/navigationbar.php'; ?>

    <!-- Footer of the site -->
    <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code in `navigationbar.php`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="login.php">Sign In</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="register.php">Create Account</a>
    </li>  
</ul>  
enter code here
```

How can I make it so these two unordered list only come up on screen if the user is logged in? I have a PHP file called `users.php` where I have a function called `logged_in`.

Below code is from `users.php`:

```
function user_logged_in () {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}
```

This is what I have done, however it seems not to be working:

Code below is a snippet from `navigation.php`, I just put a condition to see if the user is logged in and if they are then echo logged in otherwise the unordered list comes up. I am however getting a blank screen.

```
<?php
require 'users.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo 'logged in';
} else {
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="login.php">Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="register.php">Create Account</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
?>
```

I tried my best to explain the situation but however if needed more info please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally send a parameter to index.php saying if the user is logged or not,or you can include the file to later use your `user_logged_in` method and call it from the index.

And then...

```
<?php   
    include 'users.php';
    if (!user_logged_in ){
         include 'includes/navigationbar.php'; 
    }else{
        //show another navitagion bar or whatever you want for logged users
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I am sorry but I didn't include in my navigationbar.php file, I have more than those two unordered list, however I only want these two to dissapear when the user is logged in. If that makes sense . Thanks